# The 'describe' keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, spine.js

So I am a newbie in javascript and i had been going through some one else's code and I found this..

```
describe('deviceready', function() {
    it('should report that it fired', function() {
        spyOn(app, 'report');
        app.deviceready();
        expect(app.report).toHaveBeenCalledWith('deviceready');
    });
});
```

What I don't understand is: 
What exactly does the `describe` keyword do?

info:
 -  Its a **phonegap** application
 -  We are using the *spine.js* and *jQuery* libraries

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Describe is a function in the [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) testing framework.  It simply describes the suite of test cases enumerated by the "it" functions.

Also used in the [mochajs](https://mochajs.org/) framework.

Comment: It is doing this by setting up a lot of functions that give the whole test case the appearance of being a somewhat natural language sentence. This is called DSL, but it can be quite confusing for those unfamiliar with the library.

Comment: Found this via google. You should update the link. Seems to be http://jasmine.github.io/ these days.

Comment: `discribe` is also provide by another Javascript test framework "[MochaJs](http://mochajs.org)".

Answer (score 26):

`Describe` is not part of Javascript, it is a function defined in the library you used (namely Jasmine)

Answer (score 9):

According to the [Jasmine Documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/your_first_suite)

> The `describe` function is for grouping related specs, typically each test file has one at the top level. The string parameter is for naming the collection of specs, and will be concatenated with specs to make a spec's full name.

Answer (score 1):

`jest` also has `describe` function.

https://jestjs.io/docs/api#describename-fn

Answer (score 0):

The "describe" block is used to group tests together in jest.
Have a look at the following link. Go to the `scoping` section, You shall understand why and how it is been used.

`https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown`

Answer (score 0):

`Describe()` is a function in the Jest testing framework.

According to the [Jest Documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#describename-fn)

> - `describe(name, fn)` creates a block that groups together several related tests.
> - Also note, it isn't required - you can write the test blocks directly at the top level. But it can be handy if you prefer your tests to be organized into groups.
> - You can also nest describe blocks if you have a hierarchy of tests.