# Angular Material - Where is Dist?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to up my game when it comes to programming client-side, and I already use Angular for some of my work. I wanted to see how better programmers operate, so I went to check out Angular Material, specifically this [page on their coding guidelines](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/docs/guides/CODING.md#structure).

My problem is it says `NOTE: the dist directory is not version controlled` which explains why I don't see it on GitHub. The code they do have is using some kind of framework I am not familiar with, it is in the `src` folder and is full of `describe` statements that I don't really understand and are not vanilla JavaScript according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209582/the-describe-keyword-in-javascript).

Can someone help me understand their workflow and how to analyze their code if I can't get at the `dist` directory? I know I could just read the whole library as a release but I wanted to analyze each component before it was tied to the whole package, if that makes sense.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the source on the components, I believe [this](https://github.com/angular/material/tree/master/src/components) is what you're after.

If you want to know what the compile process looks like, you probably want to read [this](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/docs/guides/BUILD.md).

`describe` is just part of their testing workflow.

[edit] And to be clear, `dist` is only going to be the result of the build, so of course it is not tracked in the repo. You want to be reading the source, not the output. But downloading the source and then running a build will give you `dist` full of the compiled code.